# Is it safe to remove linux-generic-hwe-20.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel

After upgrading Kubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 to 21.10 to 22.04 LTS I now had both linux-generic-hwe-20.04 and linux-generic-hwe-22.04 installed. Weirdly enough when I tried to remove linux-generic-hwe-20.04 it automatically suggested to remove also linux-generic-hwe-22.04 (like it being dependency for 20.04??). Just in case `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` seemed to reinstall it and make it "manually installed" and after that trying to remove linux-generic-hwe-20.04 didn't want or suggest to remove anything else. But, is it safe to remove 20.04? Currently kernel 6.2.0 (from linux-generic-hwe-22.04 I assume) seems to run just fine.

Comment: The output from the apt apt command should give you more detailed information about *why* it was trying to also remove the 22.04 version.  If you could somehow reproduce that situation and give the entire output from apt it may help figure out why.

Comment: not going to reproduce, but `apt show linux-generic-hwe-20.04` has `Depends: linux-generic-hwe-22.04`. It also has ```Description: Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers (dummy transitional package)
 Transitional package for upgrades. This package can be safely removed.``` So I assume it was installed before in previous Ubuntu version and the 22.04 was added as dependency for upgrade... However why the 22.04 never got marked as manually installed is question and why 20.04 then wasn't removed automatically afterwards, if it's even written it's transitional package.